# Running an exe file from a specific location in Python

Tags: python, windows, exe

I want to create a python (I'm using 3.6.2 although if there's a solution on a newer version I'd be happy to update) program that randomly selects a game from a list of game titles and runs the .exe for the game. However, I don't know how to run a .exe file from a specific folder location ie C:Program Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is:
(You need to import `glob, random and os`)

1. Find all .exe in the folder with `file_list = glob.glob("path/to/folder/*.exe")`
2. Select a random element `game = random.choice(file_list)`
3. Run it `os.startfile(game)`

So:

```
import glob
import random
import os

file_list = glob.glob("path/to/folder/*.exe")
game = random.choice(file_list)
os.startfile(game)
```

Comment: @ThomasWade If my awnser is correct you can "accept" it by clicking the checkmark under the 2 arrows.